# How to Generate Arbitrarily Nested Vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, c++17

In C++, is it possible to generate a nested vector of depth (dimension) equal to a user defined input? For example, were a user to input an integer of value 2, one's program might create an object of type `vector< vector< vector<int> > >`. Obviously, there are numerous other ways one could easily achieve a similar behavior in C++, but I am purely interested as to whether or not the actual generation of an arbitrarily nested vector is possible. Initially, I thought this would be rather trivial, but my implementations all failed in rather curious ways.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename A> void vec_print(vector<A> in){
    cout << "{";
    for(typename vector<A> :: iterator i = in.begin(); i != in.end(); ++i){
        cout << *i << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

template<typename B> void vec_print(vector< vector<B> > in){
    cout << "{";
    for(typename vector< vector<B> > :: iterator i = in.begin(); i != in.end(); ++i){
        vec_print(*i); cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

template<typename T> auto generate(unsigned int d){
    if(d == 0){
        vector<T> in;
        return in;
    }
    return generate< vector<T> >(d - 1);
}

int main(){
    unsigned int d = 0;
    cin >> d;
    vec_print(generate<int>(d));
    return 0;
}
```

Initially, I thought this may work, though I was rather suspect of it on account of my understanding of how C++ compilers handle template functions. Using the g++ compiler with the `--std=c++11` flag, prior to crashing, the g++ compiler recursively spewed errors informing me that function return type deduction was only available under the C++17 specification. Attempting to compile this program with the `--std=c++17` flag resulted in no errors, but the compiler simply crashing. I suspect the compiler attempted to generate an infinite number of, or possibly 2^31, template functions, though I would have hoped for it to have handled this with an error warning of infinite template function generation as opposed to silently dying.

Comment: How do you think to access the nested vectors? I think, a would be to make classes for a tree like structure e.g. a base class `Vec`, a class `VecInt: Vec` with a member `vector<int>`, and a class `VecVec: Vec` with a member `vector<Vec*>` and the appropriate virtual methods to manage this.

Comment: The compiler can't deduce a type for `generate<int>(d)`. (And neither can you.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Were the compiler incapable of return type deduction, should it not output an error informing me of this? Regardless, I am fully aware the presented code doesn&#39;t compile. I am simply asking if it&#39;s possible in C++ to generate an std::vector container of user defined dimension, from a completely theoretical, non-practical, perspective. I though the provided code might add some clarity to what I am asking. Prior to user input, yes, the return type is unable to be deduced. I am agreed.

Comment: @Scheff Accessing the elements of an arbitrarily nested vector can be achieved with a recursive overloaded template function, such as the vec_print function in my code itself. I have used this function to access std::vectors of a variety of dimensions for past projects.

Comment: Yes, it should complain. The crash is a compiler bug, and you should report it. But a type can't depend on runtime values.

Comment: @ConnorMcMonigle OK. I didn't consider the theoretical background of your question.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, user-provided (as in, provided at runtime) and templates (which are an entirely compile-time concept) don't mix well. IOW, your types cannot depend from a runtime-known quantity.

Comment: `template<std::size_t, typename T> auto generate()` would be possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard sets a limit of nested template instantiation depth (1024) a conforming program should not exceed. An implementation is not required to enforce or diagnose this limit or any other implementation limit though. It can simply fail to compile any program that is "too large".

Both gcc and clang can use a flag to set a user-defined limit to template instantiation depth. In order to see what's going on, use

```
g++ -std-c++17 -ftemplate-depth-20 yourprogram.cpp >& gcc.log
```

and see how large the resulting log file is. Then increase the depth to 21 and do it again. Do it couple more times, then extrapolate your findings to `-ftemplate-depth-1024`.

Of course compiler crashing is a QoI issue and should be considered a bug. Regardless of that, your program is not conforming because it exceeds an implementation quantity.

If you want to handle vectors of arbitrary number of dimensions, you cannot use a recursive template. You have to resort to other techniques that entail setting the dimension at run time rather than at compile time.

Comment: I'd argue that it isn't exceeding the standard depth that makes it non-conforming, other than as a language lawyer; it is being infinitely deep that makes it non-conforming, which is a slightly more fundamental issue.

Comment: @Yakk An implementation is not expected to detect that the recursion doesn't terminate.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure if there is any confusion over my code, but the recursive template "generate" function is, at least theoretically, guaranteed to terminate as it takes an unsigned integer argument and decrements this input until it is equal to zero. This is not a case of infinite recursion unless you're referring to infinite recursion induced by my code in the compiler. In this case, yes, I believe this to be the issue.

Comment: @ConnorMcMonigle Template recursion ignores runtime state.  The instances are generated before the `unsigned int` is.  If you had passed the `unsigned int` as a template non-type parameter, this would not have been the case.

Comment: @n.m. The output in the resulting log file does seem to increase in size as I vary the template function generation depth level, supporting my initial suspicions and your claim. I would be willing to accept this as an answer if you elaborated on "You have to resort to other techniques that entail setting the dimension at run time rather than compile time" or definitively stated this to be impossible in your answer.

Comment: @Yakk I still don't understand what you're saying. What do you mean when you write "Template recursion ignores runtime state"? Are you saying that the infinite recursive generation of template functions during compilation is not aware of run time state, which should be obvious, or are you claiming something else. Hypothetically, were the compiler to somehow compile my program, infinite recursion could not occur which was my only point in mentioning the decremented `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ConnorMcMonigle You cannot talk about "the `generate` function" because there's no such thing in your program. `generate` is not a function. It is a function template. This template cannot be instantiated (i.e. made into an actual function, say `generate<int>`) because in order to complete an instantiation, an implementation must complete another instantiation first, which requires it to complete yet another instantiation first, which...

Comment: @ConnorMcMonigle *if you elaborated on "You have to resort to other techniques* A data structure `X` that can hold either a scalar or a vector of `X`, much like in Yakk's answer.

Comment: @n.m Thank you for clearing up my confusion. I now understand what Yakk meant by template recursion.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct element_t;

struct element_t {
  ~element_t() {}
  using element_p = std::shared_ptr<element_t>;
  using data_t = std::variant< std::vector<element_p>, int >;
  data_t data;
  element_t(element_t const&)=default;
  element_t(data_t in):data(std::move(in)) {}
  element_t()=default;
};

element_t::data_t generate( unsigned int x ) {
  if (x==0) return {unsigned{0}};
  auto ptr = std::make_shared<element_t>(generate(x-1));
  auto vec = std::vector<element_t::element_p>{ptr};
  element_t::data_t r(vec);
  return r;
}
```

test code:

```
void print( element_t::data_t const& in ) {
    std::visit(
        [](auto const& e)
        {
            if constexpr( std::is_same< decltype(e), int const& >{} ) {
                std::cout << e << "\n";
            } else {
                for (const auto& x:e) {
                    if (!x)
                    {
                        std::cout << "null\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "nest\n";
                        print(x->data);
                        std::cout << "unnest\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        in
    );
}
int main() {
    auto r = generate(10);
    print(r);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9acafd7ae8881f02)